# How to move SQLite DB in swift between projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I have created a SQLite DB in a project and populated it (in the simulator) with information that I need in another project as well.

Now, I have created another project in Xcode and I want to use my existing DB in that project as well (with the info that is already in the DB of course).

Is this possible? And how?

Short desc.: DB is created in an app in simulator and filled with data in that app.
I want to use the same DB with filled data in a new app that I am programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is copy the generated database file from the simulator's sandbox to your new project.

To find the file, add a print statement to your project that prints the path to the database file. Then you'll where it is on your computer.